# Controlling precision of doubles

Tags: c, formatting, double, precision

Hey guys I finished up this basic C program that displays an ordered set, least value, max value, average and median to a user who inputs any given set of numbers. The problem I'm having is that I have to set a standard amount of precision using something like "3.2%f" when I print the numbers, how can I print only them minimum amount of decimal places I want for each number? For example, if I input 5, 5.5, -0.2313, and 4 my program will display them in order as -0.23, 4.00, 5.00, and 5.50. How can I get it to read -.2313, 4, 5, and 5.5? Thanks in advance for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findSize();
void sortArray(int size, double num[]);
double findAverage(int size, double num[]);
double findMedian(int size, double num[]);
void findLowtoHigh(int size, double num[]);
void findHightoLow(int size, double num[]);

int main()
{
 while(1)
 {
  int size = findSize();

  if(size <= 1)
  {
   return 0;
  }

  double num[size];
  double lowest = 0;
  double highest = 0;
  double average = 0;
  double median = 0;

  fprintf(stdout, "\n"); 

  sortArray(size, num);  
  findLowtoHigh(size, num);   
  findHightoLow(size, num); 
  average = findAverage(size, num);  
  median = findMedian(size, num);

  fprintf(stdout, "\n\nLowest Value: %3.4f", num[0]);
  fprintf(stdout, "\nHighest Value: %3.4f", num[size-1]);
  fprintf(stdout, "\n\nAverage Value: %3.4f\n", average);  
  fprintf(stdout, "Median Value: %3.4f", median);

  fprintf(stdout, "\n");
 }

}

int findSize()
{
 int size;

 fprintf(stdout, "\nPlease enter size of the array: ");
 scanf("%d", &size);

 return size;
}

void sortArray(int size, double num[])
{
 for(int i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++)
 {
  int j = i+1;
  fprintf(stdout, "Please enter number %d: ", j);
  fscanf(stdin, "%lf", &num[i]);
 }

 if(size > 1)
 {
  double holder = 0;

  for(int y = 0; y < size - 1; y++)
  { 
   for(int k = 0; k < size - 1; k++)
   {
    if(num[k] > num[k+1])
    { 
     holder = num[k];
     num[k] = num[k+1];
     num[k+1] = holder;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

void findLowtoHigh(int size, double num[])
{
 fprintf(stdout, "\nFrom least to greatest: ");

 for(int x = 0; x <= size - 1; x++)
 {
  fprintf(stdout, "%3.2f ", num[x]);
 }
}

void findHightoLow(int size, double num[])
{
 fprintf(stdout, "\nFrom greatest to least: ");

 int reverse = size - 1;

 while(reverse != -1)
 {
  fprintf(stdout, "%3.2f ", num[reverse]);
  reverse--;
 }
}

double findAverage(int size, double num[])
{
 double average = 0;

 for(int a = 0; a <= size - 1; a++)
 {
  average = average + num[a];
 }

 average = average / size;

 return average;
} 

double findMedian(int size, double num[])
{
 double median = 0;

 if(size % 2 == 0)
 {
  median = (num[size/2 - 1] + num[size/2])/2;
 }
 else
 {
  median = num[size/2];
 }

 return median;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `sprintf()` do the heavy lifting and then lop off trailing zeros.

```
char *print_min_precision(char * buffer) {
  // look fo rthe decimal point, if not found return without altering buffer
  if (strchr(buffer, '.') == NULL)
    return buffer;
  // Find the last digit
  char *p = &buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1];
  // While not at the beginning and digit is zero ...
  while (p > buffer && *p == '0') {
    // Change '0' to `\0`
    *p-- = '\0';
  }
  if (p > buffer && *p == '.') {
    *p-- = '\0';
  }
  return buffer;
}


char buf[400]; // a BA buffer
// Print the number using some %f format.
// 6 here is the maximum number of fractional digits to use
sprintf(buf, "%.6f", num[reverse]);  
// Print the reduced number.
fprintf(stdout, "%s ", print_min_precision(buf));
```

In general, attempting to numerically figure out the trailing decimals has many edge conditions.  Better to print to a buffer and post-process it.  Be sure to provide adequate buffers for things like:

```
print_min_precision(sprintf(buf, "%.6f", 10e300));
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to C, can you explain what this is doing more?

Comment: Comments added.  Note: @John C solution is a good one for learners.  It will not get what you asked, but is simpler and may meet your overall goals.  OTOH, the above tries to meets your goals closely.  (Still has leading 0 when |x| < 1.0)

Comment: Thank you! this works, however when printing items with nothing to the right of the decimal point, it will still print the decimal point. For example, 5 will print as 5.

Comment: @user3457012 Added an `if()` to account for that.  The key is that you may amend the code as you see fit, adjusting for new goals as you encounter them.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to get everything you want without custom-coding from scratch, but "`%g`" takes care of at least most of what you want.  The leading zero is pretty much non-negotiable, is all.  It generally picks the most compact notation for the value, including scientific notation in extreme cases.